# How to test for website database crash

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I have designed a basic single page website using `angularjs`. I want to test the following things :

1. How much concurrent users can access this website
2. How much database at a time can be used
3. When the website would be crash

How can I check them, is there any online tool available to test them

PS : I have search on google but I got a tool `memwatch` to check memory uses. I want if there is any online tool available to test them ?

Comment: You need to look for load testing tools.[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a popular one.

Comment: Isnt there any online tool which i need not to install on localhost

Comment: Requests for tool suggestions are considered off topic.

Comment: You can google for online load test tools. Load testing is a resource intensive task, you may have to pay for it to get meaningful results. JMeter is free and easy to use

Comment: How can I know that how much database it can bear